# Extracting multiple files into their respective directories in windows

Tags: windows, unrar

I'm posting this question after extensive searches did not yield a solution to my problem.

Here's the problem: I have a folder in windows, with multiple sub folders. Each of them has 1 or more compressed (rar) folders:

-Master_folder

- sub_folder1

  - rarfolder1
- Sub_folder2

  - rarfolder1

and so on

Is there a way to extract the folder that sub_folderX (where X varies from 1 to 300) contains, into sub_folderX itself, and so on for all other sub folders?.
All posts/solutions out there on extracting multiple files simultaneously (even using CLI) talk about extracting everything into a single location. I observed similar results when experimenting with the Winrar GUI options.

However, i don't want to put them in a single location since the extracted folders have the same name. Their location within their outer folder is what differentiates them.

Comment: I'm going to leave this link here, but I'm not sure it'll be helpful for your specific case: http://www.milow.net/public/projects/parnrar/parnrar.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to scripting, you can recursively iterate over the subfolders using [command line  winrar](http://comptb.cects.com/2503-using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows) and some [batch scripting](https://superuser.com/questions/429752/how-can-i-iterate-over-directories-in-the-windows-command-prompt).

Answer (score 1):

```
#Root drive where rar files are located
$Directory = "T:\*"

$rar = Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -Recurse -Include *.rar

foreach($line in $rar){
    $unradir = $line.Directory
    $rarFileLocation = $line.VersionInfo.FileName
    C:\"Program Files (x86)"\WinRAR\unrar.exe e -ro- $rarFileLocation $unradir
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!